# MYSQL insert row in the table only if the day of execution is the last day of the month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a very simple query that inserts a count of accounts in my ns_monthly_count table. The catch is, I want this query to execute only if the day of execution is the last day of the month. So if I run this today on '2024-02-23', It should do nothing, but If i do it on 29th, It should run the query. I've tried just adding a where clause to check if the current day is equal to the last day of the month but when the query executes I get a row added in the table with value 0 in my column.

```
 INSERT INTO ns_monthly_count (count)
                SELECT count(*)
                FROM ns_accounts a
                WHERE a.statusID = 1 and curdate() = last_day(curdate())
```

This is the query. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe to embrace `curdate()` and `last_dat(curdate())` in `day()` function? Like this: `WHERE a.statusID = 1 and day(curdate()) = day(last_day(curdate()))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, nah it doesn't work, it still inserts an empty row just like before

Comment: *"I get a row added in the table with value 0 in my column."* - just to be sure, is the `count(*)` result in non-zero value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` always returns a value. The `WHERE` condition just makes it return `0` when the condition doesn't match any rows.

Use `HAVING` to filter the result set rather than the rows counted.

```
INSERT INTO ns_monthly_count (count)
SELECT count(*)
FROM ns_accounts a
WHERE a.statusID = 1
HAVING curdate() = last_day(curdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO ns_monthly_count (count)
select nr from (
    SELECT count(*) as nr
    FROM ns_accounts as a
    WHERE a.statusID = 1
)as t1 where curdate() = last_day(curdate());
```